# Select Text between two Strings C# Word Interop

Tags: c#, ms-word, word-interop

I want to select and copy a Range between two given Strings. It's also important to copy a picture or a table. It's hard to explane for me, I hope the example will help:

```
        Application word = new Application();
        word.Visible = true;
        object findtext = "Favour";
        object findtext2 = "valley";
        Document d2 = word.Documents.Open(@"Path");
        Range range = d2.Content;

        range.Find.Execute(ref findtext, ref missing, ref missing, ref 
        missing, ref missing,
        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, 
        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref 
        missing);
        range.Select();
        .........
```

Text:  
Arrived totally in as between private. Favour of so as on pretty though elinor direct. Reasonable estimating be alteration we themselves entreaties me of reasonably. Direct wished so be expect polite valley. Whose asked stand it sense no spoil to. Prudent you too his conduct feeling limited and. Side he lose paid as hope so face upon be. Goodness did suitable learning put.

What I want: 
Arrived totally in as between private. ***Favour of so as on pretty though elinor direct. Reasonable estimating be alteration we themselves entreaties me of reasonably. Direct wished so be expect polite valley***. Whose asked stand it sense no spoil to. Prudent you too his conduct feeling limited and. Side he lose paid as hope so face upon be. Goodness did suitable learning put.

Maybe I'm stupid but I work on that like a Week. All my Methods dont copy all the Tabeles and Pictures etc.

Comment: When you copy the text manually, are the pictures and tables included in the copy?

Comment: If I Select all the content in a range it's gonna copy all the extras. And when I gonna paste the range into another Document everything is all right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to something like this is to use *two* `Range` objects: one for the starting point and another for the end-point, so that one of the Ranges can then be extended to include the other. I've extended the code from the question to illustrate.

Note that it's often not necessary to *copy* content between (or within) Word documents. The `Range.FormattedText` property makes it possible to quickly transfer formatted information without putting anything on the Clipboard. Both variations are included below.

```
Application word = new Application();
word.Visible = true;
object findtext = "Favour";
object findtext2 = "valley";
Document d2 = word.Documents.Open(@"Path");
Range range = d2.Content;
Range rngEnd = null;

range.Find.Execute(ref findtext, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref
  missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, 
  ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
rngEnd = range.Duplicate;

rngEnd.Find.Execute(ref findtext2, ref missing, ref missing, ref 
  missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, 
  ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
range.End = rngEnd.End;

targetDocument.Paragraphs.Last.Range.FormattedTExt = range.FormattedText;
//range.Copy();
```

Comment: Thanks it was a good idea and it inspires me to the answer Thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer myself on the internet. I was allways searching for C# code but never tried to go with VBA code. After laughable 5 minutes I had the answer on a problem I was struggling for two week.

```
 Application word = new Application();
        word.Visible = true;

        Document doc= 
        word.Documents.Open(@"PATH");

        Range rng;
        Range rngText;
        object strStart = "STRING";
        object strEnd= "STRING";


        rng = doc.Content;
        rngText = doc.Range(0, 0);
        if(rng.Find.Execute(ref strStart))
        {
            rngText.SetRange(rng.Start,rng.End);
            rng.SetRange(rng.End, doc.Range().End   );
            if(rng.Find.Execute(ref strEnd))
            {
                rngText.SetRange(rngText.Start,rng.Start);

                rngText.Select();
                rngText.Font.Color = WdColor.wdColorAqua;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

Use regex to do your task

```
String Prefix = "Favour";
String Suffix = "valley";
String RegexForm = String.Format(@"(?<={0}\s).*(?=\s{1})", Prefix, Suffix);

Regex r = new Regex(RegexForm, RegexOptions.Compiled);

String Data = "Arrived totally in as between private. Favour of so as on pretty though elinor direct. Reasonable estimating be alteration we themselves entreaties me of reasonably. Direct wished so be expect polite valley. Whose asked stand it sense no spoil to. Prudent you too his conduct feeling limited and. Side he lose paid as hope so face upon be. Goodness did suitable learning put.";

Match m = r.Match(Data);

Console.WriteLine("Match => " + Prefix + m.Value + Suffix);
```

Match contains Start index and length of original string.

if you need to get more than 2 results, use r.Matches instead of r.Match.

hope this works. :)

Comment: How does a regex help to copy images and tables from Word?